# Java GUI - nesting panels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am attempting to make a form that takes user inputs for first name and last name and prints a welcome message combining the two. I wanted to group the input stuff together into a grid panel, then group the "Go" button and the text field that displays the message in another panel, and nest both of those together using a BorderLayout within one frame.

Generic layout:

(in a 3x2 grid)

```
First Name: __________________________  
Last Name:  __________________________  
Age:        _______________
```

"GO BUTTON" "Welcome Mark Summers"

The professor wants it all in one .java file which is my problem. I would normally separate these things then extend the classes and have no problem. What I'm trying to do is save the input and output panels under my constructor, then under my main, create

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

and then

```
add(new CalebBreckonHW3(320,120));
```

thereby putting a 320x120 panel inside my 700x700 JFrame "frame". I get an error message though that I can't reference the non-static method add(java.awt.Component) from a static context. I can't set my main to non-static or I'll get an error.

I'm in the process of adding the code to this right now through an Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CalebBreckonHW3 extends JFrame {
    private JButton jbtGreet = new JButton("Greet Me");
    private JLabel firstOprLbl = new JLabel("First name");
    private JLabel lastOprLbl = new JLabel("Last name");
    private JLabel ageOprLbl = new JLabel("Age");
    private JTextField jtfFirst = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField jtfLast = new JTextField(15);
    private JTextField jtfAge = new JTextField(3);
    // I'll get to the action events after I get this down
    private JTextField jtfGreet = new JTextField("Welcome firstname, lastname");

    public CalebBreckonHW3(int height, int width) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(height, width);
        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
        inputPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2,0,5));
        jtfGreet.setEditable(false);
        inputPanel.add(firstOprLbl);
        inputPanel.add(jtfFirst);
        inputPanel.add(lastOprLbl);
        inputPanel.add(jtfLast);
        inputPanel.add(ageOprLbl);
        inputPanel.add(jtfAge);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Greeting App");
        frame.setSize(700,700);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        add(new CalebBreckonHW3(320,120));
    }
}
```

EDIT: Adding frame in front of my add statement gets rid of the static error but it gives me an error "adding a window to a container"

Comment: Please post a short sscce or full code. The easiest work around is create a non static method to create your UI and initialize it using `new class_name().method_name();` thus because you are in a non static method you can access non static methods

Comment: @DavidKroukamp I added the full code. I am going to try your suggestion

Comment: +1 for I would normally separate these things then extend the classes and have no problem.  You should use Swing components instead of extending them, unless you're overriding a component method.  Composition over inheritance.

Comment: *"can't reference the non-static method add(java.awt.Component) from a static context"* These things should be figured out for CLI apps.  I suggest you go back through the course notes and do the earlier tasks and exercises.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you `extend` the `JFrame` class from your class, but you initiate your own `JFrame` in `main()`, also you cannot call `add()` because you are in main which is `static` while `add()` requires an instance to be created before being called, see my comment on your question, however, you should not extend a `JFrame` and rather do:

```
public class CalebBreckonHW3  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Greeting App");
       // frame.setSize(700,700); //not recommened
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

         JPanel panel=new JPanel(/*set layout if needed*/); 
         //panel.add(new JButton("Hello")); //add components to panel

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);//why did you add your JFrame again???? so I guess you'd wanna add a JPanel or something with the components you need.

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
       }

    });
 }
...
}
```

also always create a EDT (Event Dispatch Thread on which all UI components lay) I did this by `SwingUtilities.invokeLater();` also always add to a `JFrame`s contentPane via `getContentPane().add();`. Another thing, why do you add your Jframe to your Jframe? as you can see I showed an example of adding a `JPanel`

EDIT:

you make your `JFrame` a global variable and then you can use `frame.setLayout()` etc.

however if you want your current code to work do this:

```
public class CalebBreckonHW3  extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
        new CalebBreckonHW3().createandShowUI();
       }

    });
 }
 private void createAndShowUI() {
        setTitle("Greeting App");
        //setSize(700,700); //not recommened
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

         JPanel panel=new JPanel(/*set layout if needed*/); 
         //panel.add(new JButton("Hello")); //add components to panel

        getContentPane().add(panel);//why did you add your JFrame again???? so I guess you'd wanna add a JPanel or something with the components you need.

        pack();//this will override setsize and use LayoutManager
        setVisible(true);     
 }
...
}
```

but extending a `JFrame` is not recommended

Comment: How do I use the methods setLayout and setSize if I don't extend JFrame?

Comment: @Caleb: there's no need to call `setLayout(...)` on the JFrame since its contentPane by default uses BorderLayout. Also, you want to avoid calling `setSize(...)` on anything but rather let the components find their preferred sizes on calling `pack()` on your JFrame. 1+ to David's answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels +1 Thank you for the even better advice to OP on the matter I forgot about :)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp : **"always add to a JFrames contentPane via getContentPane().add(); / frame.setContentPane(...)"** both can do the same thingy :-) +1

Comment: @caleb.breckon : It would be wise, if you run through the **Basic Tutorials of Java** again. You don't extend Classes to use their methods ***(you make Objects for this purpose)***, instead you do that to change their features and add something new to them. Only methods with **protected Access Specifier (not in the same package)** are meant to be used in the term you are describing. Do watch any answer of any person in [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/topusers), you might will get an answer as to how to call methods without extending classes.

Comment: @GagandeepBali +1 oh you know your API's :)

Comment: @GagandeepBali I feel the need to defend myself by saying I'm in a Java 200 level course, so I don't really get much freedom to stray far from the examples used in class. I understand OOP quite well but this was the way the professor wanted the assignment completed in order to lay groundwork for further GUI development.